# Encoded characters in pathname

Tags: python

I am on Python Version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] (Windows 7)

I use lz4 in a script and I have a problem when reading a file with lz4.frame.open()

The filename comes from PyQt4's select file dialog and is converted to unicode with encoding='utf-8' before calling lz4.frame.open():

```
C:/Users/user/Desktop/δθμ/PREVIEW/Questionnaire.db
<type 'unicode'>
```

If code runs as

```
#fl = fl.encode('utf-8')
 with lz4.frame.open(fl, mode='r') as f:
```

I get a

```
    'filename must be a str, bytes, file or PathLike object'
TypeError: filename must be a str, bytes, file or PathLike object
```

If code runs as

```
fl = fl.encode('utf-8')
with lz4.frame.open(fl, mode='r') as f:
```

I get a

```
    self._fp = builtins.open(filename, mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/\xce\xb4\xce\xb8\xce\xbc/PREVIEW/Questionnaire.db'
```

error.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

**Edit 1**:
This is not a duplicate. As I mentioned the string returned by the filedialog has been converted to unicode with unicode(fl, 'utf-8') before the function call but it gives an error either in this case or after it HAS been encoded to str with 'utf-8'. The problem in the link you mentioned was that the returned string by the dialog was not treated like a qstring type as it should

**Edit 2**:
If "δθμ" is changed to latin characters the code runs as expected with

```
fl = fl.encode('utf-8')
with lz4.frame.open(fl, mode='r') as f:
```

but folders with these kind of letters or even spaces must be handled.

Comment: The error message `TypeError: filename must be a str, bytes, file or PathLike object` is a Python 3 error, not a Python 2 error. The class `os.PathLike` is not defined in Python 2, and Python 2 does not distinguish between `str` and `bytes`: you will get `True` back from the comparison `str is bytes`.

Comment: @filipe  # -- coding: utf8 -- – already exists in my script and as I mentioned the path has already been converted to unicode before builtins.open() is called. So I get an error either the string enters as unicode in the function call or as str utf-8 encoded.

Comment: @filipe this is not a duplicate. As I mentioned the string returned by the filedialog has been converted to unicode with unicode(fl, 'utf-8') before the function call but it gives an error either in this case or after it HAS been encoded to str with 'utf-8'. The problem in the link you mentioned was that the returned string by the dialog was not treated like a qstring type as it should.

Comment: @BoarGules the package itself (lz4.frame) check if the filename is an instance of str. Also check the python version in order to apply its logic. The error itself is package specific, not a language error.

Comment: The weird thing is that it doesn't accept unicode filepaths.. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: UTF-8 isn't going to help you. NTFS uses UTF-16 encoding natively and only has ANSI and UTF-16 interfaces.

Comment: @SimonHibbs Those encodings give the same ```No such file or directory``` error.

Comment: @Simon Hibbs +1 for indicating that 'utf-8' is not the solution in every case. For my machine which has mbcs default encoding 'utf-8' worked but on a colleague's did not. So just unicode(filename) were filename came from the file dialog did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says: filename must be a str, bytes, **file** or PathLike object:

```
if sys.version_info > (3, 6):
    path_test = isinstance(filename, (str, bytes, os.PathLike))
else:
    path_test = isinstance(filename, (str, bytes))
```

I created the source file using this code:

```
FL = u"δθμ.txt"
DATA = open(r"source.js", "rb").read()
LZ4_DATA = lz4.frame.compress(DATA)

# write compressed data to a file
with open(FL, "wb") as _file:
    _file.write(LZ4_DATA)
```

Then I gave him an instance of file object:

```
# read compressed data from a file
with open(FL, "rb") as _file:
    with lz4.frame.open(_file) as f:
        print(f.read())
```

And it works.

Comment: With ```with open(fl,'r') as _file:
                with lz4.frame.open(_file, mode='r') as f:
                    print type(f)
                    self.data = json.loads(f.read())```

I get ```<class 'lz4.frame.LZ4FrameFile'>```

and error on the ```f.read()``` part

Comment: Just desperate testing. I get the same error without the ```, mode='r'``` part. However from ```print type(f) -> <class 'lz4.frame.LZ4FrameFile'>```it looks like that file opens..

Comment: I am not sure how this works with files after reading here. https://python-lz4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: Ok filipe, I love you. This worked, and the weird thing is that for the corresponding write file action 'wb' has to be passed in both ```with open(fl, 'wb') as _file:``` and ```with lz4.frame.open(_file, mode='wb') as f:``` because in each one alone it doesn't work. Don't ask me why this happens...